# wp.editor.initialize not working as expected

Tags: wp-editor

I run a function to rename draggable/sortable items in a list, and I'd like it if the items could have a wysiwyg editor in them. I saw that some new javascript functions were introduced with 4.8, so I tried them out. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get them to work properly with dynamic elements. Here's the function that runs in the footer:

```
// Check order of sortable items
var checkOrder = (function checkOrder() {
  jQuery('.sortable-container').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.sortable-item').each(function(i) {
      jQuery(this).find('label').each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).attr('for')) {
          var oldFor = jQuery(this).attr('for');
          jQuery(this).attr('for', oldFor.replace(/\d+/g, i));
        }
      });
      jQuery(this).find('input, textarea').each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).attr('id')) {
          var oldId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
          jQuery(this).attr('id', oldId.replace(/\d+/g, i));
        }
        if (jQuery(this).attr('name')) {
          var oldName = jQuery(this).attr('name');
          jQuery(this).attr('name', oldName.replace(/\d+/g, i));
        }
      });
    });
  });
  jQuery('.wp-editor').each(function() {
    wp.editor.initialize(this.id, {
      tinymce: true,
      quicktags: true
    });
  });
  return checkOrder;
}());
```

The sorting itself works; item id's and name's are changed correctly, but when I try to run wp.editor.initialize, nothing happens. If I run it again after the fact, then it creates 2 editors on top of each other, so it must be running to an extent, but not completely. I've attempted to use the javascript functions in other contexts with similar results: works sometimes or doesn't fully initialize. Any ideas what's wrong or how I can fix it?

UPDATE:

Ok, I think I've figured out the issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I don't know how to make my script dependent on wp_enqueue_editor(), specifically the script created in class-wp-editor.php. Currently it's loading after my script. As Jarocks pointed out, it's the class-wp-editor.php that defines the wp.editor.getDefaultSettings (which is where my editor.js was failing before).

Answer (score 4):

You can use only `wp_enqueue_editor();` instead of:

```
if ( ! class_exists( '_WP_Editors', false ) ) {
    require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-editor.php' );
}
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', array( '_WP_Editors', 'print_default_editor_scripts' ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues with `wp.editor.initialize`, after a bit of troubleshooting, I found that some of the needed scripts weren't being fully loaded.

Adding this snippet of code into my plugin fixed the issue:

```
if ( ! class_exists( '_WP_Editors', false ) ) {
    require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-editor.php' );
}
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', array( '_WP_Editors', 'print_default_editor_scripts' ) );
```

Comment: Actually, I think this is close. Can I just throw this into functions.php?

Answer (score 2):

I have encounter the same issue after doing ajax call and found out that before initializing the editor we need to remove the editor call if we have already initialized editor in php and then only we need to initialize the editor

```
wp.editor.remove(editorID);
wp.editor.initialize(editorID, {
    tinymce: {
      wpautop: true,
      plugins : 'charmap colorpicker hr lists paste tabfocus textcolor fullscreen wordpress wpautoresize wpeditimage wpemoji wpgallery wplink wptextpattern',
      toolbar1: 'formatselect,bold,italic,bullist,numlist,blockquote,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,link,wp_more,spellchecker,fullscreen,wp_adv,listbuttons',
      toolbar2: 'styleselect,strikethrough,hr,forecolor,pastetext,removeformat,charmap,outdent,indent,undo,redo,wp_help',
      textarea_rows : 20
    },
    quicktags: {buttons: 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,more,close'},
    mediaButtons: false,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try `wp.oldEditor.initialize()` instead of `wp.editor.initialize()` , Make sure to enqueue the editor first